# /usr/lib/modules getting deleted on boot

Tags: systemd, kernel-modules, manjaro

This is a fresh installation of Manjaro, installed using Manjaro Architect on an existing LVM partition inside a LUKS-encrypted partition and using a separate unencrypted boot partition. I've reinstalled several times, with the same result every time.

The problem manifests itself on the second and subsequent boots, in which `systemd-modules-load.service` will fail, although the boot will continue for a bit before it hangs without any further error messages.

Fortunately after a while I can switch to another tty to examine the issue, and what I've discovered so far is this:

- The boot hangs because Xorg fails to load because the `nvidia` driver fails to load because the `nvidia` kernel module has not been loaded.
- `systemd-modules-load.service` seems to fail because `/usr/lib/modules` does not exist. It succeeds on first boot, but then after the first boot the directory is gone and subsequent boots will fail.

I can recover by reinstalling the kernel (`linux417`) and nvidia driver (`linux417-nvidia`) which will work for exactly one boot before `/usr/lib/modules` disappears again.

So my questions are:

- What could possibly be causing this during the boot process?
- How can I proceed to find more clues?

> ```
> System:    Kernel: 4.17.0-2-MANJARO x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 8.1.1 
>            Desktop: Gnome 3.28.2 Distro: Manjaro Linux 17.1.10 Hakoila 
> Machine:   Type: Desktop Mobo: ASUSTeK model: P8Z77-V v: Rev 1.xx serial: <filter> BIOS: American Megatrends 
>            v: 0906 date: 03/26/2012 
> CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i5-3570K bits: 64 type: MCP arch: Ivy Bridge rev: 9 
>            L2 cache: 6144 KiB 
>            flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 27288 
>            Speed: 1605 MHz min/max: 1600/3800 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1605 2: 1605 3: 1605 4: 1605 
> Graphics:  Card-1: NVIDIA GK104 [GeForce GTX 670] driver: nvidia v: 396.24 bus ID: 01:00.0 
>            Display: x11 server: N/A driver: nvidia resolution: <xdpyinfo missing> 
>            OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 670/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 396.24 direct render: Yes 
> Audio:     Card-1: Intel 7 Series/C216 Family High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
>            bus ID: 00:1b.0 
>            Card-2: NVIDIA GK104 HDMI Audio driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.1 
>            Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.17.0-2-MANJARO 
> Network:   Card-1: Intel 82579V Gigabit Network Connection driver: e1000e v: 3.2.6-k port: f040 bus ID: 00:19.0 
>            IF: eno1 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
>            Card-2: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter driver: ath9k v: kernel bus ID: 06:00.0 
>            IF: wlp6s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
> Drives:    HDD Total Size: 588.83 GiB used: 306.90 GiB (52.1%) 
>            ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Samsung model: SSD 830 Series size: 119.24 GiB 
>            ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Samsung model: SSD 850 EVO 500GB size: 465.76 GiB 
> Partition: ID-1: / size: 31.25 GiB used: 10.00 GiB (32.0%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-2 
>            ID-2: /boot size: 487.9 MiB used: 66.7 MiB (13.7%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdb1 
>            ID-3: /home size: 410.58 GiB used: 296.83 GiB (72.3%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-3 
>            ID-4: swap-1 size: 16.00 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/dm-1 
> Info:      Processes: 201 Uptime: 54m Memory: 15.62 GiB used: 2.46 GiB (15.7%) Init: systemd Compilers: 
>            gcc: 8.1.1 clang: 6.0.0 Shell: zsh v: 5.5.1 inxi: 3.0.10
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manjaro includes a [`kernel-alive`](https://gitlab.manjaro.org/ste74/kernel-alive) package which provides a systemd service called `linux-module-cleanup` that is supposed to clean up old kernel modules, but apparently has a bug in it that causes it to just wipe the entire `/usr/lib/modules` directory...

The solution is to just disable the service with `systemctl disable linux-module-cleanup.service`, or you could probably also just remove the `kernel-alive` package.

[Credit goes to jonathon on the Manjaro forums for suggesting this.](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/usr-lib-modules-getting-deleted-on-boot/49984/2)